# Programatically transferring mysql data between separate servers

Tags: python, mysql

Looks like there are several options:

1. **mysqldump + rsync** - can this be done for only specific data from an existing table, and not a whole table?
2. **An insert to a [federated table](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/databases/2006/08/10/mysql-federated-tables.html)** - this seems pretty untested and unknown at this point...
3. **A Python script (pull into memory from A, then insert into B)** - this would probably be pretty slow...

What kind of data warrants what method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have another option -- mysql replication!
Can you not extract that single table into its own database and replicate just that to the second server (or as many servers as you like)?

Comment: I would start by looking at the MySQL replication : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html it's not difficult at all to set up.